# Arc / Circle animation in iphone

Tags: iphone, animation

How would I animate a circle on the iPhone so that the arc starts at "0 degrees" and ends at "360 degrees"?

Advance Thanks,
Sat

Comment: You want to animate the drawing of a circle?

Comment: Can you provide more information, such as which drawing API you want to use (at a minimum)? We can't help you until you provide a good deal more information than what you have so far.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide's section on arcs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-DontLinkElementID_10). (I am assuming you are creating an app with the Cocoa Touch API, not a web app.) You also need to know how to set up a custom animation. You will have to create a custom UIView or CALayer to do the drawing, and create a property (arc degree) that can be animated with a CAAnimation object. Alternatively, you can control the animation using an NSTimer instead. You pretty much have to have a grasp of these classes (and others) to pull this off.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a great sample code about circle animation:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/24152-draw-animated-circle-iphone-using-core-graphics.html

Answer (score 0):

you should read the documentation that Felixyz provided and if you want an example of how to animate the circle have a look over the `MBProgressHUD` at this link [link text](http://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/blob/master/MBProgressHUD.m). The loader has two modes one with a `UIViewActivityIndicator` and a progress indicator (a filling circle that it is animated from 0 to 360 degress) i think the last mode is what you want.

the fallowing code is from copy/paste from that implementation that animates the circle:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGRect allRect = self.bounds;
    CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(allRect.origin.x + 2, allRect.origin.y + 2, 
                                   allRect.size.width - 4, allRect.size.height - 4);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Draw background
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // white
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.1); // translucent white
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, circleRect);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, circleRect);
    // Draw progress
    float x = (allRect.size.width / 2);
    float y = (allRect.size.height / 2);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // white
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y);
    CGContextAddArc(context, x, y, (allRect.size.width - 4) / 2, -(PI / 2), 
                                   (self.progress * 2 * PI) - PI / 2, 0);
    CGContextClosePath(context);    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

but read the documentation first! hope it helps