# How to animate an Arc?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arc / Circle animation in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172402/arc-circle-animation-in-iphone)

Following code am writing to create an Arc.

```
UIBezierPath *firstCircle = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [firstCircle addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(0, 500) radius:150 startAngle:90 endAngle:180 clockwise:NO];
    firstCircle.lineWidth = 100;
    [firstCircle closePath];
    [[UIColor blackColor]setStroke];
    [firstCircle stroke];
```

How do i animate this arc?

Comment: which kind of animation you want?

Comment: @neonsamuel: arc animating clockWise